# Cant drag any GUI component to MainWindow in Xamarin Studio(Monodevelop)?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, drag, xamarin-studio

I installed Xamarin Studio(Monodevelop) and it worked for about few days. But today i got

**Problem**:

> When i wanted to drag any GUI component to GUI builder(MainWindow) it
>   don't allow me, like it is locked or disabled?

I tried different thing to fix this(restarting Xamarin Studio(XS), restarting computer, starting new project in XS, changing preferences in XS...)and nothing worked.

Comment: Post that part as answer and then accept it. That's how SO works.

Comment: Thx. I followed your suggestion :).

Comment: `don't allow me` is not specific at all, what does that mean? did you get an error message? please edit your question or I'll downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours looking around i found solution for this problem. So i want to save other peoples time and share

**Solution**:

> I turned off my antivirus(Kaspersky IS 2015)and now XS working perfectly

If someone have experience with same problem and have better solution pls post it :).